# Kotlin Multiplatform - Multiple insertion in modules for Native on expect/actual

Tags: kotlin-multiplatform

I set up bundle.gradle like this

```
    sourceSets {
    val commonMain by getting {
        dependencies {
            implementation(libs.kotlinx.datetime)
        }
    }
    val commonTest by getting {
        dependencies {
            implementation(libs.kotlin.test)
        }
    }

    val iosX64Main by getting
    val iosArm64Main by getting
    val iosSimulatorArm64Main by getting
    val iosMain by creating {
        dependsOn(commonMain)
        iosX64Main.dependsOn(this)
        iosArm64Main.dependsOn(this)
        iosSimulatorArm64Main.dependsOn(this)
    }

    val androidMain by getting {
        dependsOn(commonMain)
    }
}
```

Also I added

```
    targets.all {
    compilations.all {
        kotlinOptions {
            freeCompilerArgs += "-Xexpect-actual-classes"
        }
    }
}
```

Why when I created in commonMain

```
expect class Converter
```

I need to add actual implementation to iosX64Main, iosArm64Main, iosSimulatorArm64Main?

Also everytime when I build project those implementation are deleted and there is error ouput how actual implementation is missing for Native

What I need to setup, so I can just add it to iOS main and not to all thres modules?

Comment: Your setup is correct you need to add actual implementation in Android and iOS source sets, no need to add to all three modules, because they all depend on iosMain. If you still have an issue could you share your full expect / actual declaration